# PHP form validation error T_String error

Tags: if-statement, header, php

what's wrong with this code i'm getting the error UNEXPECTED T_STRING.. on line 7

```
if(!$query) 
{
    die("Unable to enter into database");
}
elseif

    header("location:/Peach Mansions/confirm.php");

}
else
{
echo 'a required field is missing'; 
}
```

?>

Comment: elseif which condition?

Comment: `elseif` should be `elseif(condition)`.

Comment: you are also missing a opening tag "{" after the elseif

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong. If you have problems to understand the error message, please see the error reference we've got, it's one of the more useful resources about such errors: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Answer (score 3):

```
elseif

    header("location:/Peach Mansions/confirm.php");

}
```

should be

```
elseif (YOUR_CONDITION) {

    header("location:/Peach Mansions/confirm.php");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss `{` and condition after `elseif`.

```
elseif (condition) {
```